# Most efficient way to sort list of objects by attribute?

Tags: python, list

I have a (small) list of objects that i'd like to sort by an attribute, descending.

such as:

```
obj1.age = 1
obj2.age = 2
obj3.age = 3

list = [obj3,obj2,obj1]
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `operator.attrgetter` and `.sort`:

```
from operator import attrgetter
your_list.sort(key=attrgetter('age'), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Just for the OP's benefit: this is an **inplace sort**, so don't expect `your_list = your_list.sort(key=attrgetter('age'), reverse=True)` to work. For that, use `sorted` from iCodez answer.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid is there a difference in terms of efficiency, if the list should grow bigger?

Comment: I'll also add that `operator.attrgetter` will be more efficient than the `lambda` proposed by iCodez... Although the efficiency benefits for smaller lists would be un-noticeable

Comment: How bigger? If its _really big_ you might want to look at alternate solutions; but for most definitions of "big" `attrgetter` will be fine.

Comment: @BSG Firstly: sorting a list in place is generally more efficient than using `sorted` as that can take any iterable and produce a list. A list already has a well defined size, so traditional swap operations already have a defined range - as opposed to `sorted` which requires building a `list` first (kind of...). Second: `operator.attrgetter` works at a lower level than `lambda L: L.attribute` so avoids the creation of a lambda and so can perform the attribute access quicker.

Answer (score 5):

Since your list is small, there isn't a need to import `operator.attrgetter`.  Using [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted) with a [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) function will run just as well:

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x.age, reverse=True)
```

In the above code, `lst` is the list.  I changed the name because it is bad practice to name a variable `list` since doing so overshadows the built-in.

Also, this solution is not an in-place one.  Meaning, you can assign it to a variable:

```
new_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x.age, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Where 'x' is the model in use?

Comment: @BSG - Exactly.  `x` will be what is passed to the `lambda`, namely the object.

Comment: **descending** *cough*

Comment: This will sort in ascending order. You need to include `reverse=True` for descending.